# HttpClient 3.1 timeout is not working

Tags: java, jboss, httpclient

We are using HttpClient 3.1 in our JBoss instance, but the timeout isn't working, for some reasons it's set to 10 seconds while we set the timeout to 5 seconds (5000 ms).

```
        HttpConnectionManagerParams cmparams = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
        cmparams.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        cmparams.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
        cmparams.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        HttpConnectionManager manager = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager();
        manager.setParams(cmparams);
        HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams();
        params.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        params.setConnectionManagerTimeout(timeout);
        httpClient = new HttpClient(params, manager);
```

At the moment we get a sockettimeout after 10 seconds. Does someone now why this isn't working?

Thanks